# How to export a PureScript value to the built JS from a file that is not Main.purs?

Tags: javascript, export, purescript

In my PureScript 'Main' module, in file Main.purs, something like this:-

```
test :: Boolean
test = true
```

will be exported in the compiled, bundled and optimised JavaScript output, and will be available to my JS code.

But if I have another .purs file (in the same `src` folder), which declares another module, and it has:-

```
test1 :: Boolean
test1 = true
```

then this is *not* exported in the output JS when `pulp` builds the project.

I tried importing the other module into Main.purs, but got an error saying that the import was redundant.

What should I do to have `test1` appear in the built JavaScript file?

Comment: My pulp build command looks like this:- `pulp build --optimise --to "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\app\ps\purescript-dist.js"`.  I want optimization so I can easily read the output JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, via @hdgarrood, is to use the `--modules <comma-separated list of module names>` build option; so my build command now becomes:-

`pulp build --optimise --to "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\app\ps\purescript-dist.js" --modules MyOtherModule`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
module MyModule (test1) where
    test1 :: Boolean
    test1 = true
```

basically on your module definition you announce which values and types you want to export.
See also https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Export-lists

Comment: Are you using that module somewhere in your code? I remember (i think) that there was an issue of pulp excluding stuff that is not being used

Comment: No, I'm not using that module anywhere else in my PureScript code.  Nor do I want to... just yet.

Comment: try to at least simply import it in your main module. Pulp (or even psc) goes thru your code and excludes stuff not used. At least so you can check if this is a build issue or something completely different

Comment: If I import `test1` into Main.purs, it will be included in the built JS - as you might expect.  But I don't know if this is all by design - or, as you suggest, pulp is excluding stuff that isn't referenced explicitly by PS code.

Comment: Have a look into Purescript by Example "2.7 Removing Unused Code
Pulp provides an alternative command, pulp build, which can be used with the -O option to apply dead code elimination, which removes unnecessary Javascript from the output. The result is much smaller:"